# Convert arrays of active days to readable string

Tags: javascript, arrays, schedule, days

I need to convert an array of boolean values indicating whether the store is open on a given day.

***For example:***

**Case 1:**

```
Input data: [true, true, true, true, true, true, true]
Expected output: Every day
```

**Case 2:**

```
Input data: [true, true, true, true, true, false, false]
Expected output: Mon-Fri
```

**Case 3:**

```
Input data: [true, true, false, false, true, true, true]
Expected output: Mon-Tue, Fri-Sun
```

**Case 4:**

```
Input data: [true, false, false, true, false, false, true]
Expected output: Mon, Thu, Sun
```

**Case 5:**

```
Input data: [true, true, false, true, true, true, false]
Expected output: Mon-Tue, Thu-Sat
```

**Case 6:**

```
Input data: [true, false, false, false, false, false, false]
Expected output: Only Monday
```

I came up with [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/days-schedule-ydpboj?file=/src/index.js:668-679), but need help with cases 2-5

```
const daysLabels = [
  { label: "Monday", short: "Mon" },
  { label: "Tuesday", short: "Tue" },
  { label: "Wednesday", short: "Wed" },
  { label: "Thursday", short: "Thu" },
  { label: "Friday", short: "Fri" },
  { label: "Saturday", short: "Sat" },
  { label: "Sunday", short: "Sun" }
];

const getSchedule = ({ case: days }) => {
  let activeDays = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < [...days].length; i++) {
    const day = [...days][i];
    if (day) {
      activeDays.push({ ...daysLabels[i], value: day });
    }
  }

  if (activeDays.length === 7) {
    return "Every day";
  }

  if (activeDays.length === 1) {
    return `Only ${activeDays[0].label}`;
  }

  return "#TODO";
};
```

Sandbox - [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/days-schedule-ydpboj?file=/src/index.js:668-679)

Comment: Add your attempt in your question. Don't just link to an external source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to create groups of day ranges, along with the correct labels.

We then use a [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map) call to return only the label for each range.

I've added the 6 test cases mentioned, they should all pass.

```js
const daysLabels = [
  { label: "Monday", short: "Mon" },
  { label: "Tuesday", short: "Tue" },
  { label: "Wednesday", short: "Wed" },
  { label: "Thursday", short: "Thu" },
  { label: "Friday", short: "Fri" },
  { label: "Saturday", short: "Sat" },
  { label: "Sunday", short: "Sun" }
];

function getDayRange(input) {
    // Deal with 7 days and 1 day only first...
    if (input.filter(active => active).length === 7) { 
        return 'Every day';
    } else if (input.filter(active => active).length === 1) { 
        return `Only ${daysLabels[input.findIndex(active => active)].label}`;
    }
    // 2 - 6 days active
    return input.reduce((acc, active, idx) => {
        if (active) {
            if (!acc.length || acc[acc.length - 1].end < (idx - 1) ) { 
                acc.push({ start: idx, end: idx, label: daysLabels[idx].short, startLabel: daysLabels[idx].short });
            } else {
                acc[acc.length - 1].end = idx;
                acc[acc.length - 1].label = acc[acc.length - 1].startLabel + '-' + daysLabels[idx].short; 
            }
        }
        return acc;
    }, []).map(r => r.label).join(', ');
}

const cases = [
    { input: [true, true, true, true, true, true, true], expected: 'Every day' },
    { input: [true, true, true, true, true, false, false], expected: 'Mon-Fri' },
    { input: [true, true, false, false, true, true, true], expected: 'Mon-Tue, Fri-Sun' },
    { input: [true, false, false, true, false, false, true], expected: 'Mon, Thu, Sun' },
    { input: [true, true, false, true, true, true, false], expected: 'Mon-Tue, Thu-Sat' },
    { input: [true, false, false, false, false, false, false], expected: 'Only Monday' },
]
console.log(`Case`, '\t', 'Pass', '\t', 'Output')
cases.forEach(({ input, expected }, idx) => {
    let output = getDayRange(input);
    console.log(`${idx + 1}`, '\t', output === expected, '\t', output)
})
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my answer, This is not an optimized version.

Add below function:-

```js
function getWeekDuration(cases) {
  let index = 0;
  let weekDurationArray = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < cases.length; i++) {
    const day = cases[i];
    if (i === 0) {
      weekDurationArray[index] = [];
    }
    if (day) {
      weekDurationArray[index].push({ ...daysLabels[i],
        value: day
      });
    } else {
      if (weekDurationArray[index].length > 0) {
        index += 1;
        weekDurationArray[index] = [];
      }
    }

  }

  // remove empty arrays
  weekDurationArray = weekDurationArray.filter(item => item.length > 0);

  // get only first and last day of each week duration
  weekDurationArray = weekDurationArray.map(weekDuration => {
    // concate inner array into string
    if (weekDuration.length > 1) {
      return `${weekDuration[0].short}-${weekDuration[weekDuration.length - 1].short}`;
    }
    return weekDuration[0].short;
  });

  return weekDurationArray.join(', ');

}
```

Add return the function from getSchedule
`return getWeekDuration(days);`

Answer (score 1):

I declare a mapping array for the text, below is the example code,and you can modify the text when function return only one day or everyday.

```
// for index mapping
let indexMapping = [
    "Mon",
    "Tue",
    "Wed",
    "Thu",
    "Fri",
    "Sat",
    "Sun"
];
function getWeeks(arr){
    let list = [];
    let indexes = [];
    let item = [];
    // get all indexes
    arr.forEach((result,index) => {
        if(result) indexes.push(index);
    });

    // push each text to list
    indexes.map(i => {
        if(!indexes.includes(i-1)){
            if(item.length == 1){
                list.push(item[0]);
                item = [];
            }
            item.push(indexMapping[i]);
        }
        else if(!indexes.includes(i+1)){
            item.push(indexMapping[i]);
            list.push(item.join("-"));
            item = [];
        }
    });

    // if indexes only has one item
    if(item.length == 1){
        list.push(item[0]);
    }
    return list;
}

// for test
let testArr2 = [true, true, true, true, true, false, false];
let testArr3 = [true, true, false, false, true, true, true];
let testArr4 = [true, false, false, true, false, false, true];
let testArr5 = [true, true, false, true, true, true, false];
getWeeks(testArr2); // output will be like ['Mon-Fri']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use of `Array#map` with regular expressions may help have less hard-coding as follows:

```js
const daysLabels = [
  { label: "Monday", short: "Mon" },
  { label: "Tuesday", short: "Tue" },
  { label: "Wednesday", short: "Wed" },
  { label: "Thursday", short: "Thu" },
  { label: "Friday", short: "Fri" },
  { label: "Saturday", short: "Sat" },
  { label: "Sunday", short: "Sun" }
],

    getSchedule = ({ case: days }) => {
        const out = days.map((b,i) => b ? daysLabels[i].short : ":")
        .join(",").replace(/(?<![:\b]),[,A-za-z]*,(?![:\b])/g,"-")
        .replace(/(?<=[a-z]),(?=[A-Z])/g,"-")
        .replace(/[,\:]+/g,",").replace(/^[^A-Z]+|[^a-z]+$/g,"")
        .replace(/,/g,", ");
        return out === 'Mon-Sun' ? 'Every day' :
            !out.match(/[\-,]/) ? 
            `Only ${daysLabels.find(({short}) => short === out).label}` :
            out;
    };


const cases = [
    { input: [true, true, true, true, true, true, true], expected: 'Every day' },
    { input: [true, true, true, true, true, false, false], expected: 'Mon-Fri' },
    { input: [true, true, false, false, true, true, true], expected: 'Mon-Tue, Fri-Sun' },
    { input: [true, false, false, true, false, false, true], expected: 'Mon, Thu, Sun' },
    { input: [true, true, false, true, true, true, false], expected: 'Mon-Tue, Thu-Sat' },
    { input: [true, false, false, false, false, false, false], expected: 'Only Monday' },
    { input: [false, false, false, true, false, false, false], expected: 'Only Thursday' },
    { input: [false, false, false, false, false, false, true], expected: 'Only Sunday' }
]
console.log(`Case`, '\t', 'Pass', '\t', 'Output')
cases.forEach(({ input, expected }, idx) => {
    let output = getSchedule({case:input});
    console.log(`${idx + 1}`, '\t', output === expected, '\t', output)
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```